# How to pass a session parameter to mongoose post Update middleware?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions, middleware

I need to pass a mongoose session variable to its middleware "recordSchema.post('findOneAndRemove'...)".

I'm doing a Record.findOneAndUpdate in a controller using mongoose sessions to do a Rollback if something goes wrong. But in the middleware I make other calculations and updates that I also need to control with the same session variable in order to rollback those too.

I am running a Node + express + mongoose backend.

These is my controller where I use mongoose sessions:

```
 Record.findOneAndUpdate(Query, account, options = {
                    returnNewDocument: true
                  }).session(session).then( doc =>  { .....
```

In the Middleware after the update I need to pass the above session variable to use it inside the "calcBalance" function.

```
 recordSchema.post('findOneAndRemove',   function(doc) {
     calcBalance(0,0, doc, 'DELETE');
 });
```

Any idea of how to do it?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can access the session with doc.$session(). The $session function returns a session if one exists.